# Classifying transcendental functions for which the Hermite-Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem is true

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

The Hermite-Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem is the following statement regarding the exponential function $\exp : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$:

Theorem (Hermite-Lindemann-Weierstrass): Let $\beta_1, \cdots, \beta_n$ be algebraic numbers which are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\exp(\beta_1), \cdots, \exp(\beta_n)$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

This theorem is obviously false for algebraic functions $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, and one can easily construct transcendental functions for which the statement is false for some particular algebraic numbers $\beta_1, \cdots, \beta_n$.

How does one classify the set of transcendental functions for which Hermite-Lindemann-Weierstrass holds, perhaps up to finitely many exceptions?

Comment: Does the proof use the fact that $z\mapsto exp(z)$ is a group homomorphism whose image never vanishes?

Comment: You are asking too much! Even constructing examples of such functions is a challenging problem, there is no question of any "classification".

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko surely someone has thought of the problem of how to generalize Hermite-Lindemann-Weierstrass?

Comment: Generalize is not classify. If you want a vast generalization, read on the Schneider-Lang theorem.

Comment: @Stanley Yao Xiao: surely. For example it has been generalized to some kinds of Bessel functions (by Siegel, I suppose). But as far as I understand classification of ALL such functions is far out of reach. The crucial property that allows generalizations is that functions must satisfy some differential equations.

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for are E-functions and G-functions, as in http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/2008/08BeukersNotesDraft.pdf